# Select into without creating a new table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a number of queries like so whose results are combined at the very end so I can count the number of joins between the two different result sets and then use a union query to produce a full table of results. The problem here is that using select into creates a new table for each result instead of storing it in memory. When using PostgreSQL, how do I store each result in its own variable without creating a whole bunch of bogus tables in the database that I will have drop thereafter?

```
select distinct cust_num into t1 
from all_visits_x_cust 
where date > '06/02/2015'
and date <= '07/02/2015' 
and cust_num > 9999;

select distinct cust_num into t1_2 
from cc_calls_x_cust 
where date = '06/02/2015' 
and cust_num > 9999);

select count(*) as post_call_visitors 
into v1 
from t1_2 join t1 
on t1.cust_num = t1_2.cust_num);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the first two queries as sub-queries in your final query:

```
select count(*) as post_call_visitors 
into temp v1
from (
        select distinct cust_num
        from all_visits_x_cust 
        where date > '06/02/2015'
        and date <= '07/02/2015' 
        and cust_num > 9999
    ) as t1
join (
        select distinct cust_num 
        from cc_calls_x_cust 
        where date = '06/02/2015' 
        and cust_num > 9999
     ) as t1_2
on t1.cust_num = t1_2.cust_num;
```

Make sure to remove the `into` clause of those sub-queries. They get their names in the `as` part at the end.

By using the `temp` keyword on the second line a [temporary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html) table will be created in a special schema. It will automatically be dropped at the end of the session.

As a side note, the shorter query below should return the same results:

```
select count(distinct cust_num) as post_call_visitors 
from cc_calls_x_cust 
where date = '06/02/2015' 
and cust_num > 9999
and cust_num in (
        select cust_num 
        from all_visits_x_cust 
        where date > '06/02/2015'
        and date <= '07/02/2015' 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually wondering how to do that. In a way, that does resolve my question (so long as into v1 is taken out), but I would still like to know how to store the result in a variable of some sort without creating a new table in the database.

Comment: Depends on what you intend to do with that variable. Are you thinking of a cursor?

Comment: I suppose I am. Is it still possible to do joins between two cursors? If so, what would that syntax look like? From what I see in the documentation, the syntax for using cursors appears quite different than if one is querying on a table.

Comment: I just described the use of a tempoary table in my answer. Is this what you are looking for? Because by what you say, a cursor is not the right solution for you.

Comment: You're welcome. I just added a shorter query as a bonus :-)

Comment: The use of the non-standard `select .. into ..` to create a table based on a query is discouraged. You should prefer the standard `create table .. as select ...` statement. The best solution for this problem is using a common table expression as in klin's answer

Answer (score 3):

There are no global variables in Postgres. You can use [`with query`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) to run these queries as one:

```
with t1 as (
    select distinct cust_num
    from all_visits_x_cust 
    where date > '06/02/2015'
    and date <= '07/02/2015' 
    and cust_num > 9999
    ),
t1_2 as (
    select distinct cust_num into t1_2 
    from cc_calls_x_cust 
    where date = '06/02/2015' 
    and cust_num > 9999
    )
select count(*) as post_call_visitors 
from t1_2 
join t1 
on t1.cust_num = t1_2.cust_num;
```

You can use `SELECT ... INTO variable` in [PL/pgSQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) or [`DO` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html).